# NoSQL (BigTable...) and TimeSeries Data

Tags: time-series, bigtable

I work in an organization that collects/stores a lot of time series data (*time=value,time=value...*).  Today we use a historian to collect and process this data.  The main advantage of using a historian was to compress the data and be more efficient in terms of data storage.  However, with technologies such as Big Data, NoSQL it seems the effort to compress data (because of storage $$) is fading and the trend is to store "lots" of data.

1. Has anyone experimented with replacing a time-series historian with
   a BigData solution? I'm aware of OpenTSDB, has anyone used this in a
   non IT role?
2. Would a NoSQL database (*Cassandra...*) be a good fit for time-series
   data?  If so, what might an implementation look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the importance on just collecting or storing or is speed or ease of analysis essential?

For most reasonable data sizes standard SQL will suffice.

Above that and especially for analysis you would preferably want an in-memory and column oriented database. At the highest end this means kdb by kx.com which is used by all major banks ($$ expensive). However you ask specifically about open source, I"d consider monetdb or mysql in memory depending on your data size and access requirements.

Cassandra is one of the more appropriate choices from the nosql bunch and people have tried using it already:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra
http://synfin.net/sock_stream/technology/advanced-time-series-metric-data-with-cassandra

I found I was spending a lot of time hacking around at the smallest data level to get things to work and creating a lot of verbose code. Which was then going to spread my data over multiple servers and try to make up for the inefficient storage by using multiple machines. When I evaluated it, it's time support and functions for manipulating time were poor and I couldn't do much more than just pull out ranges easily. For those reasons I moved on from cassandra.

Comment: Where/What did you move onto from Cassandra? I think it would be nice to know. Was the new solution do what you needed it to do without "hacking around at the smallest data level"?